# Record has Long.MIN_VALUE timestamp (= no timestamp marker). Is the time characteristic set to 'ProcessingTime'

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have following topology

```
env.setTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
DataStream<Event> eventSource = env.addSource(createEventSource(kafkaTopic, kafkaBroker))
     .assignTimestampANdWatermarks(WatermarksStrategy
                               .<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSecond(20)))
     .keyBy((event)->event.getId().toString());

eventSource.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(20))
    .process(new MyProcessWindowFunction())
    .name("TESTING");

public static class MyProcessWindowFunction extends ProcessWindowFunction<Event,Event, String, TimeWindow>
{
  @Override
  public void process(String key, Context context, Iterable<Event> input, Collector<Event> out)
  {
     logger.info("currentTime = {}, currentWatermark = {} ",context.currentProcessingTime(), context.currentWatermark());
     long count = 0;
     for( Event in : input)
     {
       count++;
       out.collect(in);
     }
     logger.info(" count = {}",count);
  }
}

public static FlinkKafkaConsumer<Event> createEventSource(String topic, String broker)
{
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  prop.setProperty("bootstrap.servers",broker);
  prop.setproperty("group.id", "flinkPOCtest");
  FlinkKafkaConsumer<Event> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(topic,
                                                                     new AvroDeserializer<Event>(Event.class),
                                                                      prop);
    
  return kafkaConsumer;

}
```

Adding

```
env.setTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
```

Along with calling assignTimestampANdWatermarks on stream did solve the problem reported in earlier post where I was getting Record has Long.MIN_VALUE timestamp (= no timestamp marker). Is the time characteristic set to 'ProcessingTime'

Comment: Do i need to set
```env.setStreamTimeCharacteristics(TimeCharacteristic.EventTIme)  
```
?

Comment: What version of Flink are you using?

Comment: Hi David, I am using version flink 1.11.2

Comment: The error message indicates that the window operator has encountered an event that it cannot assign to a window because it has no timestamp. Could you have events where the timestamp is null? (No, you don't need to set the TimeCharacteristic.)

Comment: No, it should not be null. I can double check. ```event.getEventTime()``` have timestamp from epoch, the sender sends timestamp using ```System.currentTimeMillis()```
Is ```.withTimestampAssigner( (event,timestamp)->event.getEventTime() ) )``` right way to do ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: From the documentation of `setStreamTimeCharacteristics`: _In Flink 1.12 the default stream time characteristic has been changed to TimeCharacteristic.EventTime, **thus you don't need to call this method for enabling event-time support anymore**._